# Simple Junit configuration is not working

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I have some old code that I would like to test using Junit. After importing it into Eclipse it looks like this:
[image: project imported into Eclipse]

After this, I try to test the class `ACos`. I've entered some values, but it doesn't work. I get this:
[image: JUnit error screen]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your class under test is in the main package (= ""). Try without jscicalc.pobject.

Correction: If pobject is supposed to be the package, you should set it as source folder. (Right-click -> Build path on it).

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code should be under the `src` folder and not the pobject folder.

It *probably* needs to be in a package as well, but that's not as easy to tell without seeing the code within it. It should also be obvious with the errors that occur when moving it.

Comment: when i tried to move under the src i'm getting a tons of error . 

the package of the ACos class is 
package jscicalc.pobject;

Comment: Then you need to create a folder jscicalc and place the pobject folder inside. Set jscicalc as source folder then.

Comment: Yes, create a new folder (`package`) under `src` named "`jscicalc`" and then move the entire `pobject` folder--the actual folder included--under the `jscicalc` folder (`package`).

Comment: a LIFE SAVER .. thanks !!! but can someone expalain why it doesn't work when its outside the src folder ? should i place all my code there ?

Comment: Java has a very strict packaging system for its code. You cannot just throw code wherever you feel like placing it. As a result, if your code is written within a `package` (`namespace`s in most other languages like C++ and C#) then it must be included in a directory by its name, and its parent directory must be the parent package, and its grandparent directory must be its grandparent package (etc.). If there is no package defined (bad practice), then it can be in the base directory. The base directory _can_ be anywhere on the file system, but Eclipse and Netbeans assume `src` by default.

Comment: I originally hated this practice or forcefully placing my code where they want it rather than where I want it, but it's actually my favorite aspect of Java. Even in other languages, I use this practice for my namespace definitions. It simplifies finding code later on. "Where is the jscicalc.pobject.Container `class`? Oh, it's always under the source directory [wherever that is defined] under jscicalc/pobject/Container.java ." The only snag is when you have multiple source folders, which happens most often with test code (usually under `test/src`) and automatically generated code (`build/src`).